# How to execute SELECT statements in CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two `SELECT` queries let's say.

```
SELECT FullName FROM TableA
SELECT FirstName FROM  TableB
```

I want to execute both statements in `CASE` or if there is any alternative for this.

If `SELECT FullName FROM TableA` returns `NULL` or no row at all, then it should run following query:

`SELECT FirstName FROM TableB`

I could use two `CASE` statements here, but there are around 20 columns in each table and that'll make `40 CASE` statements eventually making query very lengthy.

Comment: Is there any relationship between `TableA` and `TableB`?

Comment: Do you want an answer to the single table question or the 20 column question?  They are not the same thing.

Comment: @D-Shih no there is no relationship

Comment: What is the schema, sample data and expected output please provide?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want it to return 20 columns as specified but as per the condition. If first query returns NULL it should execute the second query.

Comment: @DoonieDarkoo Return NULL where? There are 20 columns, as you said.

Comment: @AndreyNikolov NULL means 0 ROWS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT FullName FROM TableA
union 
SELECT FirstName FROM  TableB 
where not exists 
  (SELECT FullName FROM TableA)
```

[Working Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iCiWFnznh9SHEcyybHVP3R/0)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are searching for:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM TableA) 
    SELECT FullName AS Name, TableA.Field1 AS FinalField1, 
           TableA.Field2 AS FinalField2... 
    FROM TableA
ELSE
    SELECT FirstName AS Name, TableB.Field1 AS FinalField1, 
           TableB.Field2 AS FinalField2... 
    FROM TableB
```